# Httpd LimitRequestFieldSize not taken into account

Tags: apache-2.2, spnego

I have a problem configuring httpd to accept large SPNEGO authentication headers.
The request work fine with Authorization header line of up to at least 5674 bytes but break with Authorization header of more than 6178 bytes with the following answer :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.</p>
</body></html>
```

And the following error in server log (debug level)

```
[Thu Aug 23 07:26:31 2018] [error] [client x.x.x.x] request failed: error reading the headers
```

Here is an excert of the server-info page we have activated to ensure that the LimitRequestFieldSize was high enough

```
129: LimitRequestBody 52428800
130: LimitRequestFields 50
131: LimitRequestFieldsize 40960
132: LimitRequestLine 40960
```

The server is running RHEL 6.7 with stock httpd server

```
$ httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar  3 2015 12:06:14
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine with Apache 2.4 i modified the file:

/etc/apache2/conf-available/httpd.conf

according to the docs at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html

```
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/340792/size-of-a-request-header-field-exceeds-server-limit-due-to-many-if-none-match-va
# default is 8k see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html
LimitRequestFieldSize 32768
# default is 100 
LimitRequestFields 200
```

and restarted the server. You might want to fiddle with the settings

Answer (score 0):

Edit your virtual hosts and review limitation about request size.

you can check the defaults values in httpd.h (DEFAULT_LIMIT_REQUEST_FIELDSIZE for example)

example :

```
<VirtualHost ...>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ...
    #HTTP Request
    LimitRequestFieldSize 32768
    LimitRequestFields 200 
    LimitXMLRequestBody 0
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

See more at : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/core.html

Answer (score 0):

If you put your LimitRequest directives in your server config, those directives must be inserted before your VirtualHost config.